# How can I deploy form / subform (i.e. display only) changes on Notes databases?

Tags: deployment, migration, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have been asked by a client to assist in making the web frontends of number of Lotus / IBM Notes databases, used for critical LOB functions, compatible with modern browsers.

As it stands, the web frontends of these databases only work in IE7, and even then they're temperamental at best. The JS uses IE-specific extensions, everything is in tables, and they render poorly on pretty much every browser available today. With IE7 no longer in support, they want to modernise these interfaces.

I have very little experience with Notes, but as an exploratory exercise I've managed to open up the databases in Domino Designer, add a few Stylesheet / Script resources, include them in the `$$HTMLHead` variable and reworked one Form to use a frontend framework, which looks good.

Obviously working on live applications is out of the question, so my thinking is to take a copy of the NSF files, and make the changes on the copies. My question is: **how can I then deploy only the form / subform / resource changes to the 'live' NSF files?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deployment:

In your new modified database :

- You define in the Database properties that is a Database file is a master template (give a name)

In the production database :

- first do a backup ! copy (only design) to a new copy of the prod
- You define in the Database properties that it inherits from master template (same name)
- on the prod make refresh design

more details : https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_ABOUT_REFRESHING_A_DESIGN.html

Comment: Thank you for the speedy reply. This all seems clear except this line: "copy (only design) to a new copy of the prod" - how can I copy only the design? Do you mean 'copy (only design)' from the new modified database? And finally, I take it the master template is the design copy of the new modified database?

Comment: in Notes or designer when in prod: File / Application  / new copy   => Application design only

Comment: So to be clear - set the modified database as a template, give it a name, backup production, copy only the design of the modified database (making it a template?), set the production database to inherit from that template using its name, then refresh design on production.. et voila?

Comment: Before you do any of this, you should check to see if the production databases are already set to inherit from a template. If they are, then you should make your modifications in the existing templates. You can simply your changed design elements to those templates.

Comment: There is one more little hitch. There is a "Do not allow design refresh/replace" property on every design element in the production database. If that property is set for any element you are changing, you will have to manually remove the checkmark from it, otherwise the element will not be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to state the obvious, but since you have a Notes client and a Domino server, you have a quite extensive documentation at your disposal in the form of databases located in the /help/ directory. Make sure they are full-text-indexed.

And since we are on the subject of *templates*, Domino comes with a host of ready-made, ready-to-use apps that you can customize and canibalize. Look for `discussion9.ntf` for starters.

You may want to start [here](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_CHAPTER_1_INTRODUCTION_TO_DOMINO_DESIGNER_CHAP.html), then [go there](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpViewCategories.xsp?lookupName=Developing%20Form-%20and%20View-based%20Applications), and finally [that](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Tutorial-intro-to-XPages.htm) will give you the keys to build word-class web apps on Domino.

Last thing, if you are on V9, the Designer help is crap. [Grap a copy of the 8.5 version](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/documentation/dominodesigner/). Seriously.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build a modern web based front-end to existing Domino data, take a look at the following presentations:

http://www.slideshare.net/TexasSwede/ad102-break-out-of-the-box

and

http://www.slideshare.net/TexasSwede/break-out-of-the-box-part-2

As others already said, you should create a template and then just refresh/replace the design of the production database using that template.

You may want to consider working with an experienced Notes/Domino developer for that project, there are quite a few caveats and workarounds you need to know know about...